# Form action is post but echoing $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] shows get

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am having the strangest problem and I don't know how to solve it.  My form has as its first line:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

but when I echo the  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` it echoes "GET".  I am using CodeIgniter so I don't know if the problem is related to that.  I thought it might be the form helper in CI but I wrote my form all in straight HTML and I still have the problem.  The funny thing is if I copy the form into a local MAMP installation and run it, I get "POST".

I feel like I am back to basics and am missing something obvious.  Can someone help me please?  Thanks.

Comment: Disable JavaScript in your browser, reload the page and repeat. Do you get the same result?

Comment: Yes.  I disabled JS and I still get GET.

Comment: This should really not be possible unless there's some client-side or server-side trickery. I can't say anything more specific without more data. Try to use your browser's dev tools to debug this.

Comment: Maybe there is a redirect-after-post

Comment: What other data would help?  I can provide whatever might help.

Comment: No there's no redirect after the post.

Comment: @shummel7845: Which version of CI are you using? I think you might have to add the controller and view you're using with this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like CodeIgniter is running your post through some sort of cleanup process and as a results it is missing the actual method. With most php MVC frameworks, your are not supposed to access your form elements through $_POST and $_GET. They have their own wrappers to access these elements for security and cleanups...

Comment: I used the form_open syntax and I still get GET.

Comment: When I view the source with either the straight HTML or the form_open syntax, it shows method="POST".

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your form. It sounds like your MVC framework is taking the post and translating it to it's own version and then routes the request to controller. In the process, it loses the original header. just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has functionality to get the input data.

[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) are the CodeIgniter docs.

You can use it like this:

```
$this->input->post('some_data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the GET you see is simply code igniter url transformation. when you have something like localhost/main/page without htaccess and url cleanup is localhost/index.php?c=main&m=page, which is basically the GET request. By default CodeIgniter's politics on this subject is that you should always ignore using GET and only use POST; which is incredibly simple as stated in the other answers. In your form view:

```
<input type="text" name="one" /> in your form
```

and catch it in your controller with

```
$value = $this->input->post('one');
```

Don't bother doing anything manually unless it is really necessary for your task.